# Convert Autocad DWG to OBJ, FBX or similar

Tags: unity-game-engine, autocad, fbx, 3ds

How can i convert an autocad dwg or dxf file to a more 'common' format like OBJ, FBX, 3DS, etc. ?

I have tried a free software called abviewer 10 but the exported file is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I used a program called Rhino3d. You can check it here.
**https://www.rhino3d.com/download**

Comment: rhino3d on mac showed my .dwg and .dxf files as invalid, maybe they only support the newest format version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AutoCAD I/O web service to batch convert files. See documentation at http://developer.autodesk.com

In summary you can upload a .dwg along with script contains a -FBXEXPORT command, which will make the export. After that you can download the exported file.

Comment: Are you sure it could do it ?. I'm trying to use it but it's an API. Do you have any URL which could explain it.

Comment: I also can not see a clear solution to this problem. It's just an API. Is there any URL where you can upload a DWG-file and then let i convert to json

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the new Autodesk Forge API. I created a simple PHP script for this:
https://github.com/fvonellerts/AutoCADtoOBJ

If you prefer a program, use the freeware https://pcon-planner.com. It worked great for me and offers a range of export formats including obj, fbx and collada.